# How to get multiple values with a single look up in Excel with transposing the data from column to rows

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, lookup

How do I get multiple values with a single look up in Excel with transposing the data from column to rows.

Please see below image for how data is.

Input data:

[image]

Output data:

[image]

Comment: Why not the last two "Kranti"?

Comment: @Andreas am sorry that was screenshot mistake. yes, last two cells also should be copied. Thank you

Comment: Does each row always have 5 numbers?

Comment: @TomSharpe yes each rows has 5 numbers. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your data is in `Range A2:F5` and you want output to be displayed from `Cell H2` (see image from reference),

Enter following formula in `Cell H2`

```
=OFFSET($A$2,FLOOR((ROW(A2)-ROW($A$2))/5,1),0)
```

drag/copy down as required.

Enter the following formula in `Cell I2`

```
=OFFSET($B$2,FLOOR((ROW(B2)-ROW($B$2))/5,1),MOD(ROW(A2)-ROW($A$2),5))
```

drag/copy down as required.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Alternative using INDEX/ROWS

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$5,INT((ROWS(A$1:A1)-1)/5)+1),"")
```

for the name

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$F$5,INT((ROWS(A$1:A1)-1)/5)+1,MOD(ROWS(A$1:A1)-1,5)+1),"")
```

for the number.

[image]