# Converting survey response data from columns to rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have a set of data that has been exported from a system which is displayed as follows:

[Data as current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaNP4.png)

I need to have it dsiplayed as one row per respondent, with the questions as columns and the responses as the values:
[Desired data layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OE3AZ.png)

Can someone help?

I have tried v lookups but to no avail

Comment: To add, i think it would be the reverse of the formula presented in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44040056/how-to-get-multiple-values-with-a-single-look-up-in-excel-with-transposing-the-d/75865960#75865960

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a Pivot Table?
You can add "Question" as columns and Emails as rows by simply dragging them in the respective field